# Bootstrap 4 off canvas menu not working iOS Safari

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, off-canvas-menu

I'm trying to use the Bootstrap 4 off canvas menu as shown [in this example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/offcanvas/) - in iOS 10.3 Safari when closed the menu is hidden, but then opened instead of sliding to the left is only goes part way - screen grab shows it open. Works on Mac Safari and windows browsers.

I looked up most of the CSS in caniuse and all seems well for my Safari.

Code below (cut down version of the example)

[image]

**HTML**

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Offcanvas template for Bootstrap</title>
    <link href="bootstrap4_dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="bootstrap4_dist/css/SAVEoffcanvas.css?v=4" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body class="bg-light">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md fixed-top navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <button class="navbar-toggler p-0 border-0" type="button" data-toggle="offcanvas">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Offcanvas navbar</a>

      <div class="navbar-collapse offcanvas-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Dashboard <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Notifications</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Profile</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Switch account</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="http://example.com" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Settings</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>


    </nav>

    <main role="main" class="container">

        <div style='width:100%;height: 100%; background-color:  red;margin-top:20px; padding:20px;'>content</div>

    </main>


    <script src="bootstrap4_dist/js/jquery-slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap4_dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap4_dist/js/offcanvas.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
html,
body {
  overflow-x: hidden; /* Prevent scroll on narrow devices */
}

body {
  padding-top: 56px;
}

@media (max-width: 767.98px) {
  .offcanvas-collapse {
    position: fixed;
    top: 56px; /* Height of navbar */
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 1rem;
    padding-left: 1rem;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background-color: var(--gray-dark);
    transition: -webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform .3s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  .offcanvas-collapse.open {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-1rem);
    transform: translateX(-1rem); /* Account for horizontal padding on navbar */
  }
}

.nav-scroller {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 2.75rem;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.nav-scroller .nav {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  margin-top: -1px;
  overflow-x: auto;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

.nav-underline .nav-link {
  padding-top: .75rem;
  padding-bottom: .75rem;
  font-size: .875rem;
  color: var(--secondary);
}

.nav-underline .nav-link:hover {
  color: var(--blue);
}

.nav-underline .active {
  font-weight: 500;
  color: var(--gray-dark);
}

.text-white-50 { color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5); }

.bg-purple { background-color: var(--purple); }

.border-bottom { border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5; }

.box-shadow { box-shadow: 0 .25rem .75rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .05); }

.lh-100 { line-height: 1; }
.lh-125 { line-height: 1.25; }
.lh-150 { line-height: 1.5; }
```

**JQUERY**
    $(function () {
      'use strict'

```
  $('[data-toggle="offcanvas"]').on('click', function () {
    $('.offcanvas-collapse').toggleClass('open')
  })
})
```

Comment: Clear Safari cache and try again. Works now? You are welcome!

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not the problem.

Comment: what ios device u tested?

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by adding left:0 to the media query class:

```
@media (max-width: 767.98px) {
  .offcanvas-collapse {
    position: fixed;
    top: 56px; /* Height of navbar */
    bottom: 0;
    left:0,
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 1rem;
    padding-left: 1rem;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background-color: var(--gray-dark);
    transition: -webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform .3s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform .3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
    transform: translateX(100%);
  }
  .offcanvas-collapse.open {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-1rem);
    transform: translateX(-1rem); /* Account for horizontal padding on navbar */
  }
}
```